# how can i select one in table use watirwebdriver?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

when i use watirwebdriver,i come up with some questions,i can't select one in table ,it needs double click,somebody else can help me? look forward to your anwser.

```
<table id="customerName_dataTableLov" class="dataTable" style="">
<thead>
 <tr role="row">
</thead>
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
<tr class="odd">
<tr class="even">
<tr class="odd">
<tr class="even">``
<tr class="odd">
<tr class="even">
<tr class="odd">
<tr class="even">
<tr class="odd">
<tr class="even">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *i can't select one in table* ? I didn't get you

Comment: Which specific element do you need to double-click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which item you are trying to double click, but if you are trying to double click a row in the table you can do something like this:

Where x is the row index:

```
b.table(:id => "customerName_dataTableLov").tbody.tr(:index => x).double_click
```

Comment: I hava solved this problem,but thank you all the same.